# Parsing data in view layouts laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I want to make a profile photo on the admin page, this photo is in the layouts.template file, how can I get the `$profil` to be sent to the layouts.template page?

```
@if($profil->upload!=null)
<img src="{{asset('backend/assets/img/{{$profil->upload}}.jpg')}}" alt="..." class="avatar-img  rounded-circle">
@else
<img src="{{asset('backend/assets/img/mlane.jpg')}}" alt="..." class="avatar-img  rounded-circle">
@endif
```

and i created $profil in UserController

```
$auth = Auth::user()->id;
$profil = Profil_user::where('user_id',$auth)->first();
```

how do I get my `$profil` to be used in layouts.template

Comment: `laravel-5` or `laravel-4`, what is it? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: laravel 6 sir @kerbholz

Comment: Your question is not clear. My guess is that you want to use the @yield() method

Comment: You can use compact method to pass `$profil` into layouts.template page ```return view("layouts.template", compact('profil'));```

Answer (score 0):

You can share variable along all views inside below file

## app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
        //Define your user auth call here

        if(confition){
            $profile_pic = 'admin.png';
        } else {
            $profile_pic = 'default.png';
        }
        \View::composer('*', function($view){
                $view->with('profile_pic', $profile_pic);
        });
    }
```

Comment: hi can i use $profil = Profil_user::where('user_id',$auth)->first(); and return $view in AppServiceProvider?